# location finder in php with latitude and longitude with google api

Tags: php, google-maps, location

I'm trying to get location from google map with the geocode api. But after some usage the api is not working.

Here is the my code, I don't know what is happening, I have changed api_key and tried, there also nothing get from the api

```
    function addressPicker($latitude, $longitude){
        /*$latitude = '9.537086';
        $longitude = '76.886407';*/
        $geolocation = $latitude.','.$longitude;

        $API_KEY = 'AIzaSyCV1OstieLoQIssF0tBwB6jYYz_I7w1FRA';
        $request = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$geolocation.'&sensor=false&key='.$API_KEY;

        $file_contents = file_get_contents($request);
        $json_decode = json_decode($file_contents);
        $place_name = '';
        if(isset($json_decode->results[0])) {
            $response = array();
            $j = 0;
            foreach($json_decode->results[0]->address_components as $addressComponet) {
                $response2[] = $addressComponet->long_name;

                switch ($json_decode->results[0]->address_components[$j]->types[0]) {
                    case 'street_number':
                        $place_name .= $json_decode->results[0]->address_components[$j]->long_name . ', ';
                        break;
                    case 'route':
                        $place_name .= $json_decode->results[0]->address_components[$j]->long_name . ', ';
                        break;
                    case 'political':
                        $place_name .= $json_decode->results[0]->address_components[$j]->long_name . ', ';
                        break;
                    case 'locality':
                        $place_name .= $json_decode->results[0]->address_components[$j]->long_name . ', ';
                        break;
                }
                $j++;
            }
            return $place_name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you get simple map using API?

Comment: First I got the results with this api and now no data

Comment: Roger @Midhun, can tell me what did you get in file_get_contents?

Comment: please check Your URL in Address bar and check What api Returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Midhun Please Use This Code.
i just check in Your Code its Return ERROR:

*LIKE  [error_message] => Requests to this API must be over SSL. Load the API with "https://" instead of "http://".*

```
 /*$latitude = '9.537086';
    $longitude = '76.886407';*/
    $geolocation = $latitude.','.$longitude;

    $API_KEY = 'AIzaSyCV1OstieLoQIssF0tBwB6jYYz_I7w1FRA';
    $request = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$geolocation.'&sensor=false&key='.$API_KEY;

    $file_contents = file_get_contents($request);
    $json_decode = json_decode($file_contents);
    $place_name = '';
    if(isset($json_decode->results[0])) {
        $response = array();
        $j = 0;
        foreach($json_decode->results[0]->address_components as $addressComponet) {
            $response2[] = $addressComponet->long_name;

            switch ($json_decode->results[0]->address_components[$j]->types[0]) {
                case 'street_number':
                    $place_name .= $json_decode->results[0]->address_components[$j]->long_name . ', ';
                    break;
                case 'route':
                    $place_name .= $json_decode->results[0]->address_components[$j]->long_name . ', ';
                    break;
                case 'political':
                    $place_name .= $json_decode->results[0]->address_components[$j]->long_name . ', ';
                    break;
                case 'locality':
                    $place_name .= $json_decode->results[0]->address_components[$j]->long_name . ', ';
                    break;
            }
            $j++;
        }
        return $place_name;
    }
}
```

So i just set **https** in `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$geolocation.'&sensor=false&key='.$API_KEY;`

Comment: actually it returns result with **http** but after some reply it stopped and need to make as **https** and place api key also, now its perfectly working

Comment: Roger! @Midhun Happy Codding Bro

Answer (score 0):

Indeed your Google URL is not correct. This URL seems to be good:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=9.537086,76.886407&key=AIzaSyCV1OstieLoQIssF0tBwB6jYYz_I7w1FRA

```
function addressPicker($latitude, $longitude){
        /*$latitude = '9.537086';
        $longitude = '76.886407';*/
        $geolocation = $latitude.','.$longitude;

        $API_KEY = 'AIzaSyCV1OstieLoQIssF0tBwB6jYYz_I7w1FRA';
        $request = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$geolocation.'&sensor=false&key='.$API_KEY;

        $file_contents = file_get_contents($request);
        $json_decode = json_decode($file_contents);
        $place_name = '';
        if(isset($json_decode->results[0])) {
            $response = array();
            $j = 0;
            foreach($json_decode->results[0]->address_components as $addressComponet) {
                $response2[] = $addressComponet->long_name;

                switch ($json_decode->results[0]->address_components[$j]->types[0]) {
                    case 'street_number':
                        $place_name .= $json_decode->results[0]->address_components[$j]->long_name . ', ';
                        break;
                    case 'route':
                        $place_name .= $json_decode->results[0]->address_components[$j]->long_name . ', ';
                        break;
                    case 'political':
                        $place_name .= $json_decode->results[0]->address_components[$j]->long_name . ', ';
                        break;
                    case 'locality':
                        $place_name .= $json_decode->results[0]->address_components[$j]->long_name . ', ';
                        break;
                }
                $j++;
            }
            return $place_name;
        }
    }
```